# generating pdf with wkhtmltopdf inserts white space at page breaks

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am generating a PDF using pdfkitjs which connects to wkhtmltopdf

when generating my pdf white space/white div is inserted where the pagebreak happens

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tilmeldingskursus</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="academy.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; background-color: #fff}
            .w-half {width: 50%;}
            .panel {margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: #fff; border: none; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);}
            .wrapper {background-color: #f0f3f4;}
            .float-left {float: left;}
            .text-right {text-align: right!important;}
            .img-circle {border-radius: 50%;}
            .avoid {
                page-break-inside: avoid !important;
                margin: 4px 0 4px 0;  /* to keep the page break from cutting too close to the text in the div */
            }
            .table-container {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .table-row:nth-of-type(odd) {
                background: #ffffff;
            }
            .table-row:nth-of-type(even) {
                background: #f0f3f4;
            }
            .table-row  {
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 18px 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .table-cell {
                float: left;
            }
            .table-cell-1 {
                width: 8%;
                margin-left: 3%
            }
            .table-cell-2 {
                width: 15%;
            }
            .table-cell-3 {
                width: 14%;
                margin-left: 3%;
            }
            .table-cell-4 {
                width: 19%;
                margin-left: 3%;
            }
            .table-cell-5 {
                width: 32%;
                margin-left: 3%
            }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper b-a">
            <div class="wrapper-lg b-a b-dashed">
                <div class="row" style="height: 50px;">
                    <div class="w-half float-left">
                        <img src="<%= encodeURI(organization.logo) %>" alt="" class="w-md" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-half float-left text-right">
                        <%= course.now %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 style="margin: 0;">Kursus: <%= course.name %></h3>
                    <p class="page-breaker">
                        Lokation: <%= course.location %>
                        <br>
                        Dato: <%= course.date %>
                        <br>
                        Tidspunkt: <%= course.start_time %> - <%= course.end_time %>
                    </p>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 15px;">
                            <h2 class="h2 text-u-c font-thin">Deltagerlist</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-container">
                            <% for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {%>
                                <div class="table-row avoid">
                                    <div class="table-cell table-cell-1"><span class="thumb-sm"><img src="<%= encodeURI(users[i].image_path) %>" alt="" class="img-circle" /></span></div>
                                    <div class="table-cell table-cell-2"><%= users[i].profile.firstname %> <%= users[i].profile.lastname %></div>
                                    <div class="table-cell table-cell-3"><%= users[i].title.name %></div>
                                    <div class="table-cell table-cell-4"><%= users[i].division.name %></div>
                                    <div class="table-cell table-cell-5"><%= users[i].username %></div>
                                </div>
                            <% } %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

pdf example 1
[image]

pdf example 2
[image]

I am looking for a way to make the remaining whitespace before the page break transparent

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add `--margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0` arguments when using the `wkhtmltopdf` command to get rid of that whitespace.